# ZEND Framework folder/file structure

Tags: php, zend-framework2, directory-structure

I'm trying to learn zend framework. I managed to install it on my localhost. However i'm having trouble understanding the folder structure? There are 5 main folders after installing the skeleton application - config, data, module, public and vendor.

I've seen some proposed folder structures online, but how to I go about it? Do I just create folders like views, controllers, models etc?

Thanks!

Comment: the module folder does contain a Application folder? if so, look at this folder structure

Answer (score 2):

Vendor is where composer installs dependencies and libraries, config is where configuration lives, data is for cache etc, public is where your index.php and css/js/img  assets are, you are really interested in module directory that contains application modules. For the start you only really need one module - Application, inside this directory you should have config dir that has module specific config, Module.php - module bootstrap file, view with templates structured per controller and src folder with your code. Inside your src file there is your Application module namespace directory that is placed in Application directory to mimic PSR-4 autoloader namespaces it can contain your application code in this example directory structure: Controller, Form, Model. Model can contain Service, Repository and Entity folders

Answer (score 2):

If you just got started with ZF2 I suggest reading some documentation. Basic things like this can all be found in the documentation. For example [here you find more about the folder structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.intro.html#basic-application-structure).

I would also suggest taking a look at the ZF2 Skeleton application documentation/tutorial since this will help you understand the basics of a ZF2 application. [Here an example on how to structure a new module](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/modules.html#setting-up-the-album-module). Building the album application yourself is a really nice way to get started.